# How to parse Google Fit Json String with PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest, google-fit

Am trying to parse a response i get from GoogleFit API. Here is the snippet i wrote:

```
1 $result = curl_exec($ch);//execute post
2 curl_close($ch);//close connection 
3 $newResult = json_encode($result); 
4 Log::info($newResult); 
5 return $newResult;
```

And the response looks like this:

```
{ "access_token": "ya29.Il-4B1111", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": "1//09uJO5Lo7CFhyCg3333", "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read" } true
```

Line 4 is Logging instead of the response.

```
true
```

I want to store `access_token`, `refresh_token`, and `expires_in` in my `db`. I cant access the properties of the response either. Please help

Comment: [curl_exec()](https://www.php.net/curl_exec) returns `true` or `false` by default. Have you changed that behaviour?

Comment: Please what should I change curl_exec() to @ÁlvaroGonzález??

Answer (score 1):

You can decode/parse the JSON response in the following ways:

1. [object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)
2. PHP associative array

for the second option, use `true` in [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

i.e. you can use following:

```
<?php
const NL = PHP_EOL;

$json = '{
    "access_token": "ya29.Il-4B1111",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "1//09uJO5Lo7CFhyCg3333",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read"
}';

// object
$jsonObj = json_decode($json);
echo $jsonObj->access_token;
echo NL;
echo $jsonObj->refresh_token;
echo NL;
echo $jsonObj->expires_in;
echo NL;

// associative array
$jsonArr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jsonArr['access_token'];
echo NL;
echo $jsonArr['refresh_token'];
echo NL;
echo $jsonArr['expires_in'];
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/AmnqN)

Comment: This should work but the problem is ```1``` is appended to the response

[As seen here][1]
  [1]: https://3v4l.org/71W7r

Comment: use e.g. [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) [demo](https://3v4l.org/aCJt6)

Comment: The reason why you get 1 is your API retrun a redirect response instead of valid JSON data

Answer (score 1):

Some APIs respond with an invalid JSON. They add an boolean expression (true or 1) after the JSON object for security reasons. You might have to prehandle the response by yourself before parsing.

Comment: Invalid output for security reasons? Do you have any link to back up that?

Comment: Yes this what happens are boolean response was appended to the response, but i dont know how to handle this, please help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are encoding the $result for your logging. After that, you can use `json_decode($newResult, true)` - which basically converts this into an array and you can get the relevant values you need.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'YOUR API URL GOES HERE';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

curl_close($cURL);   

$json = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29.Il-4B1111
    [token_type] => Bearer
    //....
)
```

Now you can work with `$json` variable as an array:

```
echo $json['access_token'];
echo $json['token_type'];
```

Comment: this returns:
```{ "access_token": "ya29.Il-4B0HKn5VqyqTeff7C87JKjNgat5EkHkDLYiuHh1PXrIajQHB2Yitr6L0I5_cTSouqz_UjjqghpES6W0fSpXXds1xSyQedg415aRSpmMfJLQzUZvlcLy6y5MFbRLY6Kg", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 3599, "refresh_token": "1//0c5cwmuTVt4xBCgYIARAAGAwSNwF-L9Irc_-5zL26cuUikEW08chsnjQfKukp6H8HZ0VpQ9Qd4G7mbKurE4-BYZ4TX7FGP765Ra8", "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read" } 1```



and echo $json['access_token']; is empty string

Comment: Could you please paste your API URL here so i could give  it a try ?

Comment: The link you sent to me return a 302 HTTP response code (a redirect response)

Comment: try again please

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone that contributed to this thread. However, I found a library online that make things easier for me, [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/docs/oauth-web.md)